# Button click does not fire on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a lot of buttons with the class `search_camera_btn`.

When clicking on the button then it submits a form. This step works. On the other side, it should also trigger a button click event.

I wrote the event listener in a coffeescript file which sends Ajax requests, but it only works on the first click.

I put the code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/poc7667/7407354).

The Javascript **works when the button is clicked the first time, but fails on subsequent clicks.**

Actually I put a alert message in the begin of click event handler,
But it only alerts at the first time.
And there is no error message in my Firbug console. (I thought it is just didn't fire the click event handler.)

```
$(".search_camera_btn").click ->
    alert "test"
```

There are many buttons,no matter which button I click.
It always works at the first time click.
Here is my more detail source code. [download](http://d.pr/f/mnkY)

Any ideas?

---

I narrow down the buggy code.That is the "Ready to enter start" message only called at the first time.
But there is no error showed on the Firebug Javascript console and Rails console.
Should I enable some settings in the development mode ?

```
IW2 = get_camera_list: ->
    console.log("Start")

    ajax_req = $.ajax
      url: "update_camera_list/"
      type: "GET"
      success: (resp) -> 
        # console.log resp

    res = setTimeout (->
      ajax_req
      ), 500
    console.log("End")
    return
jQuery ->
  $(".search_camera_btn").click ->
    console.log("Ready to enter start")    
    IW2.get_camera_list()
```

#### Compiled CoffeeScript:

```
var IW2;

IW2 = {
  get_camera_list: function() {
    var ajax_req, res;
    console.log("Start");
    ajax_req = $.ajax({
      url: "update_camera_list/",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(resp) {}
    });
    res = setTimeout((function() {
      return ajax_req;
    }), 500);
    console.log("End");
  }
};

jQuery(function() {
  return $(".search_camera_btn").click(function() {
    console.log("Ready to enter start");
    return IW2.get_camera_list();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in the developer window of your browser on subsequent clicks?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean when you say it doesn't work? How can you tell? Are you checking your server logs and you don't see a second request? Are you looking in the JavaScript console in your browser and you're not seeing a second AJAX request? If you add a `console.log` statement in your `click` function, do you see the log statement in your JavaScript console twice or no? This will help narrowing down what your problem is.

Comment: @carols10cents I did, but it didn't show any thing on the console. I update my post :P

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `.on "click, ->` ?

Comment: No,I just copy the code from other pages, and it works. However why not? I'm trying to listen to click event? :P

Comment: I've included the compiled CoffeeScript, for my sanity and the sanity of everyone else.

Comment: I think that you need to use .on as @RichPeck suggested. If your content is generated after the document has loaded, jQuery on method will still intercept the event. Try this: $(document).on('click', '.search_camera_btn', (-> alert('Got the event!') ))

Comment: Since this [jsfiddle][1] works i think there's a thing based on your environment. 
Are you sure that your .search_camera_btn elements aren't handled in another place? (for e.g. a stopPropagation is being putted on another handler?)


[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/EbA4b/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
    jQuery ->
      $(".search_camera_btn").click ->
        console.log("Ready to enter start")    
        IW2.get_camera_list()
```

For:

```
jQuery ->
  $(".search_camera_btn").click ->
    console.log("Ready to enter start")    
    IW2.get_camera_list()
    return
```

And let me know if it helps ;)

Answer (score 13):

The reason that the handler is only being fired once is because
the ".click" handler only applies to elements that are currently attached
to the DOM.  If you replace the HTML after making the AJAX call, the event handlers will be lost.
You should use an event delegate instead.  Try this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    return $("body").on("click", ".search_camera_btn", function() {
        alert("Ready to enter start");
        return IW2.get_camera_list();
     });
});
```

This statement basically says, if there are any elements in the DOM now, or in the future, that have a class of "search_camera_btn", and are contained within the "body" element, then fire the click handler.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I bet that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure nothing else in your application's javascript is failing (like a simple syntax error can cause this sort of thing). Also have you tried this in different browsers? I've had a similar problem where my Ajax would work fine in Chrome but would only post once in Firefox because of some add-ons/extensions (and then I disabled them and they worked).

Also, I'm not sure if I read your gist correctly but it looks like you're specifying .click in both the jQuery of the application.js and in the btn.js.coffee, and I'm pretty sure that section in application.js should just be watching for the element's function/result and not specifying the click again.

If nothing else works, also check out ajax's .done completion call about halfway down the page here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . Then show the picture list as a function after .done so you know your ajax post is always completing before moving on to the next thing. (Ajax problems like this often tend to be server side when a call doesn't complete or there's a loop somewhere)